# change the sherlock action bar tab text color on tab selected

Tags: android

I am new to sherlock action bar.I have implemented sherlock action bar with view pager.I want to change the tab text color on tab selected. I am confused with selector and styles.Pls suggest me some beginner tutorials

Answer (score 0):

Please check out the default ABS demos app on [github](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock)

And [customizing default Action Bar elements](http://android-developers.blogspot.co.uk/2011/04/customizing-action-bar.html)